# Inconsistencia de diseño / Design inconsistency

Tags: discusión, soporte

Este es el logo de la página principal de sitio / This is the logo of the site main page:

[image]

Este es el favicon y SE logo / This is the favicon and SE site logo:

[image]

[image]

Es necesaria la inconsistencia pudiendo ser fácilmente solucionable? Basta con escoger uno de los dos.

Is the inconsistency necessary when it could be easily solved?
It's just about choosing one of both.